S3 bucket policy
I am trying to use the AWS s3 commands to list and get objects from the terminal. I already configured the credentials with the private key of the IAM user, and I added the policy in the bucket as well, but it does not matter what I do, I always get this error:

aws s3 ls s3://folder-staging/file01.txt --profile folder-staging
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

This is my policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:user/manolo"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::folder-staging",
                "arn:aws:s3:::folder-staging/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I also trying a more permissive variation but it does not work either:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::folder-staging",
                "arn:aws:s3:::folder-staging/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I also switched "Block public access (bucket settings)" to Off
User policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

aws sts get-caller-identity --profile manolo
{
    "UserId": "yyyyyyyy",
    "Account": "xxxxxxxx",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:user/manolo"
}


Guy thanks for your answers, but the issue was in another place. I just remembered a very interesting tool in the AWS universe :), called "IAM Policy Simulator", well, after calling the GetObject and ListBucket actions, I saw that it was another policy (created for another developer, not me), that denies all of this, and that's why it was not working, now everything is fine.
Thanks

If you wish to grant access to a specific user, it is typically better to grant access via a policy on the IAM User rather than via a Bucket Policy. Bucket Policies are typically only used to grant 'public' or cross-account access.
It would be similar to the policy you already wrote:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::folder-staging",
                "arn:aws:s3:::folder-staging/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


First and most important. Go and put back the "Block public access" flag, unless you want your bucket to be publicly accessible, which judging from your bucket policy i think is not your case. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html)
From what you describe i suppose you want to access your bucket from the user arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/manolo.
So there is a couple of things to check for throubleshooting:

Your user should have an IAM identity policy that allows it to do s3:ListBucket and s3:GetObject on the desired bucket. The resource policy alone is not enough. That policy is used to restrict access, not to allow it. As a rule of thumb you will always need a policy on the user/role that is trying to perform an action that allows it to do so. (docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_change-permissions.html#users_change_permissions-add-console)
Check that you are trying to do the s3 ls with the correct credentials. To do so you can use the AWS CLI, just run:

aws sts get-caller-identity

and see if you are actually acting as the user arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/manolo.
Let me know if this helps you. I will also leave here a blogpost with some throubleshooting for your error: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403

Hi, thanks for your answer, sorry I ommited all these information, but yes, the user has attached the right policy , this user has full s3 access, but for some reason I still getting the error. On the other hand, I have a few s3 profiles, and when I connect I use the parameter --profile to indicate the profile I wanna use for establish the connection. aws sts get-caller-identity --profile manolo returs the right user.
